# How to cancel webhost when process is stopping

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, cancellation-token

I've just tried using the `async Task Main` method in a templated web API (dotnet 5).  Here's my boiler plate code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

I noticed that the RunAsync takes a cancellation token and I'd like that to be based on the application closing.

**My question** - what's the correct (standard) way to setup a cancellation token here that's linked back to the process shutdown?

I could do something like this:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) => { if (e.IsTerminating) cts.Cancel(); };
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (s, e) => cts.Cancel();
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => { e.Cancel = true; cts.Cancel(); };

    await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync(cts.Token);
}
```

But wondered if there's a more standard approach that I'm missing.

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this `UseConsoleLifetime()` that can be set on the webHost builder:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => 
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Now `Microsoft.Hosting.LifeTime` handles the cancellation token for me.  Great!

Answer (score 4):

.NET host design puts the logic to terminate the application based on external events (e.g. CTRL + C in console app) into an implementation of [IHostLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) interface.

Existing implementations of `IHostLifetime` include [console](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.cs), [windows service](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetime.cs) and [systemd](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Systemd/src/SystemdLifetime.cs). This is basically what `UseWindowsService` and `UseSystemd` extensions register, see e.g. [WindowServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions source](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.cs). The lifetimes implementations typically use [IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to shut down the application. The default web host setup includes the console lifetime.

Using this approach, a single application can be configured as a console app, windows service, or use whatever other shutdown triggers required.

It should not be otherwise necessary to register the cancellation listener to any runtime shutdown events such as `UnhandledException` or `ProcessExit` as the application process is getting torn down anyway. The hosting concept is a based on Task-based asynchrony, it does not spawn any subsequent processes or similar resources that would stay alive beyond the exit of `Main`.

For more details, see [Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ihostapplicationlifetime-interface) and [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ihostapplicationlifetime) documentation pages.